# How to force HTTP2 client to reconnect to server?

Tags: server-side, http2, reconnect

It is needed to make a HTTP2-response, which will force a client to reconnect to the same server to the same address.

In case of HTTP/1.1 it could be done sending `307 Temporary Redirect` response with `Connection: close` header.

In HTTP/2 `Connection: close` header is ignored and redirect is performed without reconnection, which brings to redirect loop error.

Also, I've tried to send `421 Misdirected Request` response to client with the same url, but Chrome browser is do nothing after receiving this response.

What is the most proper way to force a HTTP/2 client to reconnect? Which server response can be send? Maybe some kind of `GOAWAY` frame?

Comment: What's the purpose of forcing the disconnection/reconnect? Are you sure there's not an HTTP 2 solution to your problem that *doesn't* require tearing down the existing connection?

Answer (score 2):

Following the graceful shutdown procedure that RFC 7540 recommends should result in a reconnection:

> A server that is attempting to gracefully shut down a    connection
>   SHOULD send an initial GOAWAY frame with the last stream    identifier
>   set to 2^31-1 and a NO_ERROR code.  This signals to the    client that
>   a shutdown is imminent and that initiating further    requests is
>   prohibited.  After allowing time for any in-flight stream    creation
>   (at least one round-trip time), the server can send another    GOAWAY
>   frame with an updated last stream identifier.  This ensures    that a
>   connection can be cleanly shut down without losing requests.

Regarding 421 handling in Chrome, this bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=546991 was opened to have Chrome re-open a new connection to the server, it's seen some activity recently.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the way on HTTP/2 to ask a client to reconnect for further requests is to send a `GOAWAY` frame to it. How this works depends on your server side implementation or framework for HTTP/2 support. E.g. a framework could intercept your `Connection: close` header and treat it as a request to close the connection after the request. But I guess most HTTP/2 implementations wouldn't like to do that, since they guess the header targets only the current request scope and not the whole connection. Alternatively the framework could provide a way in the request handler to not only access the request and response data but also to get a reference to the HTTP/2 connection, which can be used to send the GOAWAY.

Answer (score -1):

This may help you [Google HTTP2](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/http2/)

Comment: Could not find any information in the link about how a server can force client to make a reconnection.